# Setting "t" as separator in QGIS

Tags: qgis, import, text, delimiter

My QGIS project and all text files have been separated into columns with the letter `t`.

How do I go back to the previous setting?

In the picture you can see the letter t is considered as a separator (ex: commen-aire) we would expect commentaire in a single column

These are unicode text files.

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot to show this? Are these text files being used as layers? Is this in the attribute table view?

Comment: you have probably lost a `\ ` from a tab `\t` in the custom delimiter properties

Comment: It may not be a trivial exercise to repair broken delimiters. If the data is all numeric you might not need to start over, but if there's text in the file, then you're likely to have figure/ground issues.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming these are being read in from CSV files using the Delimited Text layer, check the "File Format" section of the dialog. I can replicate your field breaks with this:

[image]

Note the `t` in the "Custom delimiters" "Others" box.

You don't say what separator you are using, but if its commas then selecting "CSV" in the options should work. You've not shown us your process that results in your badly-broken table so I can't be certain.